# Test fail when using Cypress session

Tags: javascript, session, cypress

I have the following code:

```
export function backofficeAuthenticate(username, password) {
    cy.session(['Login'], () => {
        cy.request({
            log: false,
            method: 'POST',
            url: getBackUrl('/login.htm'),
            qs: {
                redir: getBackUrl('/back'),
            },
            followRedirect: false,
            body: {
                'Login_login-email': username,
                'Login_login-password': password,
                'action[Login_login:login]': 'login',
            },
        });
      });}
```

And I am calling a function to login like that:

```
 export function loginWithAdmin() {
    backofficeAuthenticate(Cypress.env('WEB_LOGIN_USERNAME'), Cypress.env('WEB_LOGIN_PASSWORD'));
}
```

My code in the test is:

```
    import { loginWithAdmin, httpAuthentication } from '../../cypress/support/bestreviews.js';

describe('Dashboard types quick smoke', () => {

    const endpoints = [
        '/dashboard',
        '/dashboard/articles',
        '/dashboard/archive',
        '/dashboard/syndicated',
        '/dashboard/tribunearticles',
        '/dashboard/giftguides',
        '/dashboard/blogposts',
    ];

    

    endpoints.forEach((endpoint) => {
            it(endpoint, () => {
                cy.visitBackOffice(endpoint);
                httpAuthentication();
                loginWithAdmin();
                cy.checkErrorFree();
                cy.get('.dashboard-entries').should('exist');
                cy.get('[data-content="topic-info"]').should('exist');
            });
        });
    });
```

After I execute the code, I always got an error:

> (uncaught exception) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null
> (reading 'style') TypeError The following error originated from your
> application code, not from Cypress.
>
> > Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
>
> When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your application
> it will automatically fail the current test.
>
> This behavior is configurable, and you can choose to turn this off by
> listening to the uncaught:exception event.Learn more

Does anyone know what I am missing? I think the problem is with cypress session, but not sure how to proceed...

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that cypress catches exceptions generated from your application you can add this in `cypress/support/e2e.js`

```js
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  // returning false here prevents Cypress from
  // failing the test
  return false
})
```

Note: One thing to note is that if you add this, cypress will not catch exceptions generated from your application, which is not a good practice, because you want your tests to catch exceptions.

Comment: Thank you, will look at it later and check is it ok.